# Hibernate, assigning multiple columns as primary key

Tags: database, nhibernate, hibernate, database-design

My database table `items`:

```
item_id int(11) autoincrement not null
item_name varchar(22) not null
version_start_date datetime not null
version_end_date datetime
```

The primary key is (item_id,version_start_date).

version_start_date and version_end_date keep track of changes to the table row. If the item name is modified, then a new row is added and the old row version_end_date is updated.

I tried to model this in hibernate, but composite-key doesn't allow a generator to be present as per the schema. I need a generator for itemid.

I don't want to go with a natural id, because I have to generate the id. Instead I am thinking of also having field item_version_id.

```
item_version_id autoincrement not null
item_id int(11) autoincrement not null
item_name varchar(22) not null
version_start_date datetime not null
version_end_date datetime
primary key(item_version_id)
unique key(item_id,version_start_date)
```

Only an ID element can have a generator. But I have two generators.

How do I model this in hibernate?

Answer (score 3):

You need a custom hibernate type combined with  a custom id generator.  I don't think there is any way around this.

this should get you started.
[Hibernate ID Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495536/hibernate-id-generator)

edit--
I would highly recommend you use surrogate keys, as recommended in the hibernate documentation. If you don't you risk making things a *lot* more difficult than they need to be.

You can still model your versioning scheme as natural keys and query off that.

edit for your update--

Evidently this is possible now (wasn't back when when we had to solve this problem)

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2060

you can now specify any generator for a part of a composite key. thats pretty sweet.

I still  think your best bet is to use surrogate keys to make hibernate happy and your life easy, and a natural-key to satisfy your business requirements.

Comment: I thought over too many alternatives and little confused. can you please provide with an example?

Comment: @algorist example of natural key or example of custom hibernate type?

the natural key documentation is here 

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-naturalid

its pretty easy.

a custom hibernate type example is not so trivial.

Comment: can you please have a look at the question now.

Comment: So, I have to apply the patch to get this working. Because, the version I am using, the hibernate dtd throws me an error. I read about surrogate and natural keys in wiki..even searching in google, didn't give me an real world schema for this. Do you know any good explanation on this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @algorist -- i don't understand -- you can't find documentation on surrogate and natural keys?  Its all in chapter 5 of the hibernate manual.

Comment: Even though composite supports generator, mysql doesn't allow more than one auto_increment  per table :(